# Using FBLinkShareParams and FBAppCall

Tags: ios, facebook

When we download the FacebookSDK (version 3.16.1), we get a few sample apps.
One of them is called *HelloFacebookSample*, I grabbed code from there and made it work my way inside an app of mine.

Now, here is my question. If I tap the “Post Status Update” button (in HelloFacebookSample), the following code gets executed.

```
NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developers.facebook.com/ios"];

FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] initWithLink:urlToShare
                                                               name:@"Hello Facebook"
                                                            caption:nil
                                                        description:@"The 'Hello Facebook' sample application showcases simple Facebook integration."
                                                            picture:nil];

BOOL isSuccessful = NO;
if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]) {
    FBAppCall *appCall = [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:params
                                                     clientState:nil
                                                         handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                             if (error) {
                                                                 NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                                             } else {
                                                                 NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                             }
                                                         }];
    isSuccessful = (appCall  != nil);
}
```

It works well, Facebook opens and one can see “*Say something about this…*” as placeholder.
Instead of this placeholder, I would like to set my own preset text. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prefill the text, this is by design. Prefilling the text would violate the Platform Policies you agree to when you create an FB app.

Comment: I see. I am fine with no previously filled text. My real concern is that the description I put seems too long and gets cut like this:
"This is the description ...."
I just would like to find a way around. Can you think of any?

Comment: There are some rules I was not fully aware of here:
If I use SLServiceTypeFacebook through SLComposeViewController to make a post I can preset the text any way I want.
On the other hand if I use FBLinkShareParams and FBAppCall like I in this example, then I cannot preset the text.
Has this something to do with the fact that in the first case a login is needed but not in the second?

Comment: No, the Platform policy is simply a policy. The Facebook SDK enforces it via code, it can also be enforced in other ways. In general, when you create an FB app, you agree to the policy, and agree not to prefill the text. Even if the iOS social framework allows you to do it, doesn't mean you should, and doesn't mean there won't be enforcement down the line.

Comment: Interesting! I see that I must learn. That brings 2 questions to my mind.
You use the term FB app. When one puts a button to link any kind of app to FB. Does that make it a FB app? Or is it a bit more complicated? My second question is, in case there is no URL or image to include. What is the point of putting a FB button in my app, if I am not supposed to put any kind of prefilled text related to my own product?
I guess there must be some cases, where it still makes sense, but still.
Forgive me if I am showing some lack of basic understanding, related to FB usage or so ….but one has to learn.

Comment: 1. When I say FB app, I mean that you went to developers.facebook.com and created an app. 2. The user must type in the message themselves.

Comment: OK, thanks. Now it's clear. That means when I use SLServiceTypeFacebook through SLComposeViewController, where I do not need to go developers.facebook.com(and create an app); it is not a FB app. But in the other case where I went indeed to developers.facebook.com and created an app; it is a FB app. I was not aware of this difference. For me it was only 2 different ways to get more or less the same result.